# How to find div on checkbox change event instead of hardcoding div id in jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors

I want to use jquery function to find all div on checkbox change event instead of hard-coding **id** and **class** name in jquery selector.

There are 2 sections in my code with Id name section1 and section2 and so on chkall event i want to find this div id and pass this as jquery selector

This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" CssClass="checkallparent" runat="server" Text="Select All" />
    </div>
    <div class="abc">
        <ul class="list">
            <div id="section1" class="section"> 
                <li class="carousel-border">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chkParent1" class="chkParent" /> --Parent of below 2 checkboxes
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chkchild1" class="chkChild"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chkchild2" class="chkChild"/>
                </li>
            </div>

            <div id="section2" class="section">
                <li class="carousel-border">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chkParent2" class="chkParent" />--Parent of below 2 checkboxes
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chkchild3" class="chkChild" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chkchild4" class="chkChild"/>
                </li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(".checkallparent").change(function () {
    //on this event i want to check all my checkboxes and this is how i am doing.
    if ($("#chkAll").prop('checked') == true) {
        //for section 1
        $(this).find('input:checkbox[id^="chkParent1"]').prop('checked', true)
        $(this).closest('.section').find('input:checkbox[id^="chkchild1"]').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).closest('.section').find('input:checkbox[id^="chkchild2"]').prop('checked', true);
        // Above is not working but when i do like below it is working
        $("#section1 .chkParent").find('input:checkbox[id^="chkParent1"]').prop('checked', true)
        $("#section1 .chkParent").closest('.section').find('input:checkbox[id^="chkchild1"]').prop('checked', true);
        $("#section1 .chkParent").closest('.section').find('input:checkbox[id^="chkchild2"]').prop('checked', true);

        //I dont want to hardcode like this instead i would like to use any jquery function 
        //which would find this 1st div and 2nd(for eg section1 and section2 etc... )

    }
});
```

So can anybody tell me how to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should help you figure that out. The first `change` event sets the parent checkboxes, then triggers off the change event of those parents.

The second change event handle the parent items.

```
$(".checkallparent").change(function () {
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    var parentCBs = $("input[type='checkbox'].chkParent");
    parentCBs.each(function(i, el) {
        el.checked = checked;
        $(el).trigger("change");
    });
});
$("input[type='checkbox'].chkParent").change(function () {
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    var div = $(this).closest("div");
    var childCBs = div.find("input[type='checkbox'].chkChild");
    childCBs.each(function(i, el) {
        el.checked = checked;
    });
});
```

[Here is a working Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/dzh7cz07/)